# React - Trying to pass fields from one page to another in Touchable Highlight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

I have a RN app. Trying to pass fields (in the HEADER) from one page to another (from this "Chat" page TO = "Profile View" page. However, its not working.

I put a Touchable Highlight around it, but not working.

I keep getting Error = cannot find 'first_name'. So I dont think its getting the info INSIDE = render () {.....

You may disregard from 'state' down. Just wanted to show you the page layout.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
  Share,
  AlertIOS,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  KeyboardSpacer,
  StatusBar,
  DeviceEventEmitter
} from "react-native";

import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import { GiftedChat } from "react-native-gifted-chat";
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import moment from "moment";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import Email from "../modules/email";
import withPreventDoubleClick from "../components/withPreventDoubleClick";
import CircleImage from "../components/circleImage";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {
  ActionSheetProvider,
  connectActionSheet
} from "@expo/react-native-action-sheet";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const TouchableHighlightEx = withPreventDoubleClick(TouchableHighlight);
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

@connectActionSheet
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const first_name = this.props.profile.first_name;
    const uid = this.props.user.uid;
    const user = this.props.user;
    const profile = this.props.profile;
    const profileId = this.props.profile.uid;
    //const uid = this.props.profile.uid;
    //const { id, birthday, first_name, work, imageObj, education } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === "ios" && (
          <Entypo
            name="dots-three-vertical"
            size={25}
            style={{ paddingRight: 7, marginTop: 7 }}
            color={"#fff"}
            onPress={this._onOpenActionSheet}
          />
        )}

        {Platform.OS !== "ios" && (
          <Entypo
            name="dots-three-vertical"
            size={25}
            style={{ paddingRight: 7, marginTop: 15 }}
            color={"#fff"}
            onPress={() => this._showModal()}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

export default class Chat extends Component {


  //static navigationOptions = {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({


    render() {
      const first_name = this.props.profile.first_name;
      const uid = this.props.user.uid;
      const user = this.props.user;
      const profile = this.props.profile;

    },


    headerTitle: (

            <TouchableHighlightEx
          underlayColor="transparent"
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("ProfileView", {
              first_name,
              birthday,
              id,
              uid,
              date1,
              date2,
              date3,
              profileUid,
              profile: rowData,
              user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user
            })
          }
        >

      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >

        <CircleImage
          size={30}
          uri={navigation.state.params.profile.imageObj.img_0}
          style={{
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            resizeMode: "contain",
            alignSelf: "center"
          }}
        />
        <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 17, marginLeft: 5 }}>
          {navigation.state.params.first_name}
        </Text>
      </View>

      </TouchableHighlightEx>

        ),


    title: navigation.state.params.first_name,
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerRight: (
      <ActionSheetProvider>
        <App
          method={navigation.state.params._showModal}
          goBack={navigation.state.params._goBack}
          details={navigation.state.params.first_name}
          profileId={navigation.state.params.profileUid}
          uid={navigation.state.params.user.uid}
          user={navigation.state.params.user}
          profile={navigation.state.params.profile}
        />
      </ActionSheetProvider>
    ),


    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      // iOS
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
      // Android
      elevation: 0
    },



  });



  state = {
    messages: [],
    user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
    profile: this.props.navigation.state.params.profile,
    modalShow: false,
    blockUnblockText: "Block User",
    datePlan: null,
    isDateLoaded: false,

    canLoadEarlier: true,
    loadingEarlier: false
  };

  currentMessage = 20;
  messagePerPage = 20;
```

Comment: Please reformat your code to be more legible. Get rid of unnecessary console.logs or comments so it's easier to read.

Comment: We have "removed" the console logs. However, that is not the issue. It is VERY easily readable.